How do I tell if a CPU is 'powerful enough'?
As a bit of side information, I use a ThinkPad from like 2012 for almost everything and it works flawlessly. Its got a Core i5 with 16(?) GB or RAM and thats more than I need for almost anything.
However, sometimes I need to run applications that don't function on machines with lower specifications and am looking to purchase a good Desktop that I can kind of forget exists but will be more than enough to run just about anything.
I was looking into a board with a AMD Opteron 6275 and realized that although it included (as far as I know) ample specs in all capacities I was unaware if
it included a powerful CPU.
How can I tell if a CPU is "powerful"? What should purchasers like me be looking for when purchasing a CPU?

Powerful is deeply relative. At the moment, I have a core i9 9900k (great single threaded perf), an older broadwell EP Xeon which was cheap, and outperforms my main pc in multithreaded perf and a pair of atoms, which are cheap and do things.

TLDR: buy a Xeon if you need power at a low price. Buy a modern mid/low end for that level of perf at 1/10th the power. This might be the worst choice possible.
A quick look at the processor shows its a bulldozer based opteron, There's a few considerations here. The bulldozer based systems used something called a core complex,so essentially your 16 cores was something between having hyperthreading and single cores. Its a very old system. I'd note core count alone needs context in general, either cause of this or cause many modern machines have different types of cores - either dramatically different like intel's performance and efficiency cores or the C cores in new zen systems.
I've thrown in a set of benchmarks, and you can literally get better performance off a low end, current gen processor - a core i3 N305 would likely give you up to 1.5x the same performance at 1/10th the power usage. I'll post another answer going into this if needed, but I suppose we're really looking at a low cost, high performance system with a server processor. There's a ton of options but I recently did a build off some parts I picked up from aliexpress. I did a few things right, and a few things wrong, but I think the motherboard/processor combination I did is a good, significantly better performing analog to what you're trying to build.
I'd recommend a LGA 2011 platform processor and motherboard. There's excellent documentation on the v3 processors/ the "X99 platform" and Miyconst tends to have good reviews on what's cost effective, and tweaking them. These are cheap well understood and heavily tested and reviewed boards.
I went for a slightly more modern motherboard and processor platform - this is the specific one I got, but there's a ton of variations. I went with DDR4 partially for parts commonality between by PCs, and that its starting on the sweet spot of cost effective obsolescence .
So lets talk about the general thought processes here - and not just about performance.
Firstly, and critically, when building a machine on an older platform, maintainability is important. I'm assuming that since the Opteron 6276 is a OEM server chip, the motherboard was in a server. Was it a standard footprint (EATX? ATX?). Would it take an ATX PSU, a standard server PSU like an flex ATX
or something unique to the platform? Do you need ECC (both in terms of your use case, and support) for your machine or workload?
If I wanted to run a powerful windows machine, the processor I run isn't supported by windows 11 (and there's no TPM). I'm using windows 10 for initial benchmarking and testing and intend to run linux otherwise. I'd need a more modern machine for windows use.
I'd look at workloads - a desktop system with fewer cores would have better single thread performance than a server processor. My core i9 9900k has better single thread and worse multithread performance than the slightly older E5-2680 for example.
Practically I'd also look at footprint (do you really want a 4U machine), noise (servers can get loud) and TDP. I'd also look at support for coolers - since while I can literally order a LGA2011 compatible heatsink anywhere, can't really find one for a socket G34.
I'd generally want NVMe boot support (fast storage covers for a lot of sins) as well.
Basically this isn't a powerful processor by any stretch of the imagination.

First many website compare CPU with each other and you start by finding your CPU.  Also you have a 12 year old CPU so any modern CPU is going to be much faster.
I looked up core i5 and there are about 50 different core i5 range from 12th place all the way down to 800th place so that isn't enough info.
Although, it is not as comprehensive testing as other sites www.userbenchmark.com is one such site.  It ranks all CPU in order from the most power to the least.  However, they test for generic workloads and may not include your type of work.  3dmark and https://www.phoronix.com/ and many other sites not only compare, but offer software you can download, some paid for, to test and rank your specific PC.
This will give you perspective on how fast you are now, and how much faster each CPU is than your existing one.
If you do a lot database or 3d work you should also search for benchmark regarding those specific work loads.
This is an over simplification, but decide how many times faster you want your CPU to be and select one that much faster.
The question is are your work loads single or multi-threaded?  If multi-threaded how many cores can it use.  Thus buying one with significantly more cores, like a 64+ core threadripper, is a waste of money if your programs can only use 4 cores.  Sure you could run 16 programs each using 4 cores at once but is that a workload you would encounter?  For most people the answer is no.
Upgrades to ddr4/5 and NVMe storage will almost dramatically increase the speed of the CPU.
Unless we know more about the type of work loads you use, it hard to make a good cpu choice.  Obviously if you want to spend $5000 or more than go ahead.
Also it should be noted some tasks are better suited for the GPU with CUDA or OpenCL.  Many GPU have 2000,4000,8000, or even 16000 cores.  If the task is suitable for GPU acceleration 4000 cores beats 64 any day.  However, not all tasks are suitable for GPU acceleration and GPU are much more limited/dedicated to graphics processing so many tasks won't be able to run on a GPU.
